# How to get email domain name from email ID in T-SQL assuming there is more than one delimited value?

Tags: sql, t-sql, email, dns

I have an email ID column and would like to extract the domain only accounting for sub domains if applicable. My current query is assuming the first delimited value only

For instance 'abc@gmail.com' = gmail

However, if the email is like 'abc@gmail.co.com' it will be extracted as gmail.co - I want it to be gmail only as well

My query:

```
SUBSTRING(col_email, 
    CHARINDEX('@', col_email) + 1, 
    LEN(col_email) - CHARINDEX('@', col_email) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(col_email))) as domain
```

Comment: What about if the email address was `steve@meta.stackoverflow.com`? HOw about `Jane@dba.stackexchange.co.uk`?

Comment: Well that is quite simply my question, I have just been able to extract domain between first '.' and '@'

Comment: So, from your perspective, the *domain* is `meta` and `dba` respectively, *not* `stackoverflow` and `stackexchange`?

Comment: Yes for simplicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a few of `CHARINDEX`s and `SUBSTRING` for this. This *assumes* that all email addresses are valid (so have a `.` after the `@`) and that you don't have any outlier email addresses like `Steve"@"home.has_a_valid_address@mydomain.com`:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@',Email)+1,CHARINDEX('.',Email,CHARINDEX('@',Email)) - CHARINDEX('@',Email) -1) AS YourDomain
FROM (VALUES('abc@gmail.com'))V(Email)
```